# Event listener to get next item in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Creating a script to cycle thru items in an array, ideally both next and previous items. Currently the script works however, it always begins at the zero index, no matter which item is currently displaying in the 'mock modal' being created. Full script here:

```
var dogs = document.querySelectorAll(".dog-div");
var dogArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(dogs);

var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
var modalTitle = document.querySelector(".modal-title");
var modalImg = document.querySelector(".modal-img");
var leftArrow = document.getElementById("left-arrow");
var rightArrow = document.getElementById("right-arrow");

for (i = 0; i < dogArr.length; i++) {
    dogArr[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalTitle.textContent = this.dataset.dogName;
        modalImg.setAttribute("src", this.dataset.dogImage );
    })
}

function nextDog() {
  i = i + 1;
  i = i % dogArr.length;
  return dogArr[i];
}

rightArrow.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(nextDog());
})
```

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: Sure @palaѕн, jsfiddle can be found here: [https://jsfiddle.net/pj6079sz/4/](https://jsfiddle.net/pj6079sz/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dogs = document.querySelectorAll(".dog-div");
var dogArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(dogs);

var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
var modalTitle = document.querySelector(".modal-title");
var modalImg = document.querySelector(".modal-img");
var leftArrow = document.getElementById("left-arrow");
var rightArrow = document.getElementById("right-arrow");

function makeIterable(arr) {

  var cur = 0;
  arr.next = function () {
    return ++cur >= this.length ? false : this[cur];
  };
  arr.prev = function () {
    return --cur < 0 ? false : this[cur];
  };
  arr.cur = function () {
    return cur;
  };
  arr.setCur =  function (pos) {
    cur = pos;
  };
  return arr;
};

makeIterable(dogArr);

function clickedClassHandler(name,callback) {

    var allElements = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");

    for(var x = 0, len = allElements.length; x < len; x++) {
        if(allElements[x].className == name) {
            allElements[x].onclick = handleClick;
        }
    }

    function handleClick() {
        var elmParent = this.parentNode;
        var parentChilds = elmParent.childNodes;
        var index = 0;

        for(var x = 0; x < parentChilds.length; x++) {
            if(parentChilds[x] == this) {
                break;
            }

            if(parentChilds[x].className == name) {
                index++;
            }
        }

        callback.call(this,index);
    }
}

clickedClassHandler("dog-div",function(index){
    dogArr.setCur(index); //here's where you set the current position of the array based on whichever item is selected.
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalTitle.textContent = dogArr[dogArr.cur()].dataset.dogName;
    modalImg.setAttribute("src", dogArr[dogArr.cur()].dataset.dogImage );
});

rightArrow.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
if (dogArr.cur() < dogArr.length-1) {
  console.log(dogArr.next());
  modalTitle.textContent = dogArr[dogArr.cur()].dataset.dogName;
  modalImg.setAttribute("src", dogArr[dogArr.cur()].dataset.dogImage );
}
})

leftArrow.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
if (dogArr.cur() != 0) {
  console.log(dogArr.prev());
  modalTitle.textContent = dogArr[dogArr.cur()].dataset.dogName;
  modalImg.setAttribute("src", dogArr[dogArr.cur()].dataset.dogImage );
}
})
```

You need to remember the position of the clicked item whenever you click on the button.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this creates the same results as my original code as seen at this jsfiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/bc7ow35j/](https://jsfiddle.net/bc7ow35j/)

Comment: Apologies, understood the problem wrong, I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Leroy I've updated the answer again to actually display the respective images on next and previous buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `nextDog` function you are using variable i, which was used in previous for loop. After for loop variable `i` has the value of `dogArr.length`. Hence in first call of nextDog `i` value determined by:

```
i = (dogArr.length +1) % dogArr.length;
```

You get 2nd position(index=1) of `dogArr`

So I suggest, you to use another global variable to track current index of showing item.

```
var dogs = document.querySelectorAll(".dog-div");
var dogArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(dogs);
//global tracker
var currIndex=dogArr.length;

var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
var modalTitle = document.querySelector(".modal-title");
var modalImg = document.querySelector(".modal-img");
var leftArrow = document.getElementById("left-arrow");
var rightArrow = document.getElementById("right-arrow");

for (i = 0; i < dogArr.length; i++) {
    dogArr[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalTitle.textContent = this.dataset.dogName;
        modalImg.setAttribute("src", this.dataset.dogImage );
        //get item index from dataset
        currIndex=this.dataset.indexNumber;
    });

   //set item index here
   dogArr[i].dataset.indexNumber=i;
}

function nextDog() {
  currIndex = currIndex + 1;
  currIndex = currIndex % dogArr.length;
  return dogArr[currIndex];
}

rightArrow.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(nextDog());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to post my answer after some time. More or less, got a working example with the below codepen:

https://codepen.io/leroyrosales/pen/GRpMwdg

```
var dogs = document.querySelectorAll(".dog-div");
var dogArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(dogs);

var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
var modalTitle = document.querySelector(".modal-title");
var modalImg = document.querySelector(".modal-img");
var leftArrow = document.getElementById("left-arrow");
var rightArrow = document.getElementById("right-arrow");

var current = dogArr.length;

for (i = 0; i < dogArr.length; i++) {
    dogArr[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        current = dogArr.indexOf(this);
        modalContent(this);
        this.classList.add("active");
    })
}

function modalContent(modal){
  console.log(modal);
  var dogName = modal.dataset.dogName;
  console.log(dogName);
  var dogImg = modal.dataset.dogImage;
  console.log(dogImg);
  
  modalTitle.textContent = dogName; 
  modalImg.setAttribute("src", dogImg );
}

function nextDog() {
  current = current + 1;
  current = current % dogArr.length;
  return modalContent(dogArr[current]);
}

function prevDog() {
  current = current - 1;
  current = current % dogArr.length;
  return modalContent(dogArr[current]);
}

rightArrow.addEventListener("click", function() {
  nextDog();
})

leftArrow.addEventListener("click", function() {
    prevDog();
})
```